# R extracting list components to create a data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list that looks like `List_Lookup`. Each list within the list contains a different numbers of entries.

```
ListCodes <- list(List1 = c(1,2,3), List2 = c(5,2,4,3,6))
DF_Lookup <- data.frame(CODE = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), NAME = c("AAA111", "BBB222","CCC333","DDD444","EEE555","FFF666"))
List_Lookup <- lapply(ListCodes, function(x) DF_Lookup$NAME[x])
```

What I am after is something like `ListDF` where each pairing of list name and list entry is a unique row in a dataframe. I am sure there is a simple solution to this, I am just having a hard time finding it.

```
ListDF <- data.frame(LIST = c("List1","List1","List1","List2","List2","List2","List2","List2"), NAME = c("AAA111", "BBB222","CCC333","EEE555","BBB222","DDD444","CCC333","FFF666"))
```

Comment: `stack(lapply(List_Lookup, as.character))`

Comment: @Psidom Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stack` to convert the list names to one column and list values to another; Here is from the docs `?stack`:

> Stacking vectors concatenates multiple vectors into a single vector
>   along with a factor indicating where each observation originated.

```
stack(lapply(List_Lookup, as.character))

#  values   ind
#1 AAA111 List1
#2 BBB222 List1
#3 CCC333 List1
#4 EEE555 List2
#5 BBB222 List2
#6 DDD444 List2
#7 CCC333 List2
#8 FFF666 List2
```

To set up desired column names:

```
setNames(stack(lapply(List_Lookup, as.character)), c("CODE", "LIST"))

#    CODE  LIST
#1 AAA111 List1
#2 BBB222 List1
#3 CCC333 List1
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks. That does exactly what I am after. I knew I was missing something simple!

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the list to a data.frame with `purrr::imap_dfr`, which would let you simply join:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ListCodes <- list(List1 = c(1,2,3), 
                  List2 = c(5,2,4,3,6))
DF_Lookup <- data.frame(CODE = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                        NAME = c("AAA111", "BBB222","CCC333","DDD444","EEE555","FFF666"))

ListCodes %>% 
    imap_dfr(~data_frame(LIST = .y, CODE = .x)) %>%    # convert into data.frame
    full_join(DF_Lookup, by = 'CODE')
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>    LIST  CODE   NAME
#>   <chr> <dbl> <fctr>
#> 1 List1     1 AAA111
#> 2 List1     2 BBB222
#> 3 List1     3 CCC333
#> 4 List2     5 EEE555
#> 5 List2     2 BBB222
#> 6 List2     4 DDD444
#> 7 List2     3 CCC333
#> 8 List2     6 FFF666
```

Add `%>% select(-CODE)` if you don't want the join column anymore.

Comment: Which version of `tidyverse` contains `imap_dfr`?

Comment: Crap, yeah I keep forgetting they haven't released that version to CRAN yet. You can install the development version with `devtools::install_github('tidyverse/purrr')`